# Error converting Detectron2 torchscript model to CoreML using coremltools

Tags: python, coreml, coremltools, detectron, torchscript

I have a Detectron2 model that is trained to identify specific items on a backend server.  I would like to make this model available on iOS devices and convert it to a CoreML model using coremltools v6.1.  I used the export_model.py script provided by Facebook to create a torchscript model, but when I try to convert this to coreml I get a KeyError

```
def save_core_ml_package(scripted_model):
    # Using image_input in the inputs parameter:
    # Convert to Core ML neural network using the Unified Conversion API.
    h = 224
    w = 224
    ctmodel = ct.convert(scripted_model,
                         inputs=[ct.ImageType(shape=(1, 3, h, w),
                                              color_layout=ct.colorlayout.RGB)]
                         )
    # Save the converted model.
    ctmodel.save("newmodel.mlmodel")
```

I get the following error

```
Support for converting Torch Script Models is experimental. If possible you should use a traced model for conversion.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/repo/URCV/src/Python/pytorch_to_torchscript.py", line 101, in <module>
    save_trace_to_core_ml_package(test_model, outdir=outdir)
  File "/usr/repo/URCV/src/Python/pytorch_to_torchscript.py", line 46, in save_trace_to_core_ml_package
    ctmodel = ct.convert(
  File "/opt/python-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/_converters_entry.py", line 444, in convert
    mlmodel = mil_convert(
  File "/opt/python-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/converter.py", line 190, in mil_convert
    return _mil_convert(model, convert_from, convert_to, ConverterRegistry, MLModel, compute_units, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/converter.py", line 217, in _mil_convert
    proto, mil_program = mil_convert_to_proto(
  File "/opt/python-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/converter.py", line 282, in mil_convert_to_proto
    prog = frontend_converter(model, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/converter.py", line 112, in __call__
    return load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/torch/load.py", line 56, in load
    converter = TorchConverter(torchscript, inputs, outputs, cut_at_symbols, specification_version)
  File "/opt/python-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/torch/converter.py", line 160, in __init__
    raw_graph, params_dict = self._expand_and_optimize_ir(self.torchscript)
  File "/opt/python-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/torch/converter.py", line 486, in _expand_and_optimize_ir
    graph, params_dict = TorchConverter._jit_pass_lower_graph(graph, torchscript)
  File "/opt/python-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/torch/converter.py", line 431, in _jit_pass_lower_graph
    _lower_graph_block(graph)
  File "/opt/python-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/torch/converter.py", line 410, in _lower_graph_block
    module = getattr(node_to_module_map[_input], attr_name)
KeyError: images.2 defined in (%images.2 : __torch__.detectron2.structures.image_list.ImageList = prim::CreateObject()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it looks like you are using a torch script model:

> Support for converting Torch Script Models is experimental. If
> possible you should use a traced model for conversion.

if possible try to use a traced model e.g.:

```
dummy_input = torch.randn(batch, channels, width, height)
traceable_model = torch.jit.trace(model, dummy_input)
```

followed by your original code:

```
ct.convert(traceable_model,...
```